# How to search value in two Array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, find

I have some data in MongoDB, the data structure is like

```
{"a":{"b":[1,2,3,4,5],"c":[a,b,c,d,e]}}

1--->a
2--->b
3--->c
4--->d
5--->e
```

I want get the right part value by the left 
like search b by 2

How can I do this 
Thank you very much

Comment: what are you using to query your database? `mongo shell`?

Comment: what is the purpose of the `b` array? Am I getting it correct: you have some value `X` which has the index `i` inside `b` field. You want to get the `i`th element of `c` array?

Comment: Correct ! That is what I want do

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible to achieve in an easy way, if it is possible at all. Are you bound to this structure or you can modify your model?

Comment: Well, thank you very much, The real data of b field is like 101.321, I set the b field as key and c field as value, but MongoDB seems like doesn't support key contains dot(.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is to modify your structure to be able to make a query you want. My suggested structure is the following:

```
{
   a: [
         {b: 1, c: "a"},
         {b: 2, c: "b"},
               .
               .
               .
      ]
}
```

Then having your `b` value, you will be able to get the `c` one:

```
db.yourCollection.find({"a.b": "your_b_value"})
```

**UPDATE** *by request of the question author*

To make your query by range execute the following query:

```
db.yourCollection.find({"a.b": {$gte: 400.0}, "a.b": {$lte: 400.3}})
```